# $W = T_1 \cos^2(\theta) + T_2 \sin^2(\theta)$ solve for $\theta$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If I have $W = T_1 \cos^2(\theta) + T_2 \sin^2(\theta)$ where $W,~ T_1$ and $T_2$ are all $3D$ vectors that all lie on the same plane, how do I rearrange this equation to get theta by itself?

Comment: $W$, $T_1$ and $T_2$ all have to lie in the same line.  In your other equation, $W$ has to lie on a specific ellipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> $$W = T_1\cos^2(\theta) + T_2\sin^2(\theta)$$

Note that $\;T_1\cos^2\theta = T_1(1 - \sin^2\theta)$

$$W = T_1(1 - \sin^2\theta) + T_2\sin^2\theta$$

$$W = T_1 + (T_2 - T_1)\sin^2\theta$$

$$\dfrac{W - T_1}{T_2- T_1} = \sin^2\theta$$

Now solve for $\sin \theta$ and then take $\sin^{-1}(\sin \theta)\;$ substituting your solution to $\;\sin \theta$.

Comment: Nice! I was writing another solution, but this one is fine.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks. One more question though if you have the time, is there a similar thing I can do for W = T1*cos(theta) + T2*sin(theta) ie -without the squares?

Comment: The identity used is $\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta = 1$. You'd need to search for an identity that might work, but I'm afraid it would be messy, and likely *not* allow you to isolate theta.

Comment: You can substitute: $\;\cos^2\theta = \dfrac{1+\cos(2 \theta)}2\;$ and $\;\sin^2\theta = \dfrac{1-\cos(2 \theta)}2$ and solve for $\cos 2\theta$, then for $2\theta$, then halve the solution to get $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to plug in $\cos^2(\theta) = \dfrac{1+\cos(2 \theta)}2$ and $\sin^2(\theta) = \dfrac{1-\cos(2 \theta)}2$. Hence, we get
$$W = \dfrac{T_1 + T_2}2  + \dfrac{T_1 - T_2}2 \cos(2\theta) \implies \cos(2 \theta) = \dfrac{2W - T_1 - T_2}{T_1-T_2}$$
Hence, $$2 \theta = 2n \pi \pm \arccos \left(\dfrac{2W - T_1 - T_2}{T_1-T_2}\right) \implies \theta = n \pi \pm \dfrac12 \arccos \left(\dfrac{2W - T_1 - T_2}{T_1-T_2}\right)$$